# how to get custom attribute of application in okta using java

Tags: java, attributes, okta

Recently we decided to add applications and link it with okta user profiles.I added some  custom attribute under the application and tried to retrieve it in java using getUnmapped.get("variable name") but it returns null.

How do i resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you retrieving properties from the User profile object using the Okta Java SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delayed reply.This is actually not a problem but something which I overlooked.
We have been creating applications (to increase modularity)and linking them with users wherever required.I needed to store and retrieve values in applications.
So I simply use

```
appUser=user.getProfile();
String valueRequired=appUser.getUnmapped.get("attribute name");
```